# How to show div content in HTML when using BootStrap 3 navbar items

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with BootStrap 3 CSS styling and have created the following:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button> 
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Home</a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                       <li><a href="#mywork" onclick="return show_div('mywork');">My Work</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#myprofile">Profile</a></li>
                       <li class="dropdown">
                           <a href="#other" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Other actions <b class="caret"></b></a>
                           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                               <li><a href="#contactme">Contact Me</a></li>
                           </ul>
                       </li>
                </ul>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#actions" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Actions <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#updateprofile">Update profile</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#logout">Logout</a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
</div>

<div id="home" style="display: none;">
    Test Data
</div>
```

And from this I am trying to display the div at the bottom which I have given the id "home" which corresponds to the #home href given on the nav bar.

The trouble I am having is that I cannot show the div with the id of home when the Home element of the navbar is clicked, am I doing something wrong or can someone point me in the right direction? I have spent a lot of time trying to work this out but cannot.

EDIT:

JavaScript show_div function:

```
<script>
    //Functon to show divs from the nav menu
    function show_div(toShow)
    {
        var show = document.getElementById(toShow);
        show.style.display = "";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Show us the javascript. Where's the implementation of show_div?

Comment: I have added the show_div function, this is something I thought might work although it has proven not to

Comment: Apologies that I forgot to add the JS

Comment: Your anchor tag has a onclick event but you are passing the ID of `mywork`... I seen no elements with the id of `mywork` Change the onclick event call to `onclick="show_div('home');"` and see if your div with the **Test Data** appears.

Comment: @NewToJS, that has worked! That was a stupid mistake on my park, can you add that as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your anchor onclick event is sending the wrong id

```
<li><a href="#mywork" onclick="return show_div('mywork');">My Work</a></li>
```

It should be sending `home` to target the div tag with your test data:

```
<div id="home" style="display: none;">
    Test Data
</div>
```

Change the onclick to:

```
<li><a href="#mywork" onclick="show_div('home');">My Work</a></li>
```

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: That is perfect, thank you very much :) It was just a silly mistake on my part that caused my problem.

Comment: It's a simple error to make, sometimes when you make errors like this, you can't see them because you think it's something much bigger and look in all the wrong places.

Answer (score 3):

Why you don't want to use jQuery like this:

```
<a id="sh" style="cursor:pointer">Show Home</a>
<div id="home" style="display: none;">Test Data</div>

<script type="text\javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sh").click(function () {
        $("#home").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery isn't tagged in the question, also the question isn't how to toggle elements. The question is "*am I doing something wrong or can someone point me in the right direction*" so correcting the existing source code would be the correct answer.

Comment: Agree! Just alternative way.

Comment: since the function would be used for multiple elements, you might want to think of using a class. Just a tip for next time or for your own use. Here's a quick example http://jsfiddle.net/485fzt0j/ Its better than having to add the .click() for each element.